# How do I import a text file into a SQLite3 table using python

Tags: python, sqlite

I currently have a txt file of movies which contain a movieID,Movie Name, and genre.
Example:

```
1,Toy Story (1995),Animation|Children's|Comedy
2,Jumanji (1995),Adventure|Children's|Fantasy
3,Grumpier Old Men (1995),Comedy|Romance
4,Waiting to Exhale (1995),Comedy|Drama
5,Father of the Bride Part II (1995),Comedy
```

I am trying to import this file into a SQLite3 table created with Python:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('CSC 452 Final.db')
c=conn.cursor()
```

## Drop Tables

```
c.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_movie''')
print("Table temp_movie dropped.")
```

## Create Table for Movies

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE temp_movie (
    MovieID          NUMERIC (5),
    movie_title_year VARCHAR2 (255),
    movie_categories VARCHAR2 (255),
    CONSTRAINT movies_movieID_PK PRIMARY KEY (
        MovieID
    ))''')
print("Table temp_movie successfully created.")
conn.commit()
```

What's the best way to import my text file into this database with the delimiter being ','?

Comment: skip the song and dance with python, and use sqlite3 itself.  Use import or CSV virtual tables (https://www.sqlite.org/csv.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can read in the `txt` file and split on `,`:

```
file_data = [i.strip('\n').split(',') for i in open('filename.txt')]
new_data = [[int(a), *b] for a, *b in file_data] #convert string id to integer
conn = sqlite3.connect('CSC 452 Final.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.executemany('INSERT INTO temp_movie VALUES (?, ?, ?)', new_data)
```

Comment: I tried this and I got this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/romariomason/Desktop/Graduate School/CSC 452/Final/CSC 452 Final.py", line 7, in <module>
    file_data = [i.strip('\n').split(':') for i in open('movies.txt')]
  ...
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3041: invalid continuation byte

Answer (score 1):

I would have used python csv module to do that:

```
with open(<txt file>,'rb') as f: 
    dic_reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    value_list = [(each_row['MovieID'], each_row['movie_title_year'], each_row['movie_title_year']) for each_row in dic_reader]

c.executemany("INSERT INTO t (MovieID, movie_title_year, movie_title_year) VALUES (?, ?);", value_list)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: @MarioMason Does that assignment allow you to copy the code from the internet?